# AudioKit Module compiled with Swift 4.0.3 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1

Tags: audiokit, swift4.1, xcode9.3

I have updated to Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1 and using AudioKit 4.1.
Though I am getting this error when building.
[image: Error]

How would I update the modules to Swift 4.1?

Comment: I just received a message from AudioKit they are updating the module. "The frameworks need to be recompiled with the new Xcode. We actually have a new build coming out soon just for this (version 4.2), so just hold on a little bit longer..."

Comment: Hi  @uplearnedu.com , I need your help... Im trying to run that project "github.com/swiftingio/SingTest" but getting that error "Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2.1 compiler: /Users/aliapple/Desktop/SingTest/Pods/AudioKit/iOS/AudioKit.framework/Modules/AudioKit.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule". Can you help me in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rebuild your copy of AudioKit with the build_frameworks.sh script off of the develop branch or wait till tonight or tomorrow night when we will release the new version.

Comment: The directory is empty. Should we have the 4.1 version installed and put in there the build_frameworks.sh of the develop branch and run it?

Comment: 4.2 is available now.

Comment: Directory is still empty after using `pod 'AudioKit', :git => 'https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit.git', :branch => 'develop'` and 4.2.1

Comment: 4.2 is up and pod specs updated and working. Thanks Aurelius for speedy update.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get rid of this is, go to https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/releases find the version compatible with the Xcode that you are using and change you pod file version. I was using Xcode 10.1 so I changed my file pod 'AudioKit', '4.5' it solved my problem.